# Sonicwall Connecting to VPN: failed to find connection entry for message id xxxxxxxx

Tags: vpn, sonicwall

I am trying to connect to a VPN using SonicWall but after authentication, I am getting `"failed to find connection entry for message id xxxxxxxx"`. Any ideas?

Note : I am not getting this error each time I connect to VPN. But sometimes it starts happening and I don't find any way to connect to VPN again.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just if someone getting same issue. I removed "SonicWALL" shortcut from windows recent items `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent` and re-opened SonicWall VPN client. It worked.